# how to send data to be printed via bluetooth J2ME

Tags: java-me

can someone please help. i am trying to send data to a thermal printer using bluetooth. i understand how to discover the devices but not able to connect or know how to send the stream of data to be printed. what do I use here ? there is OBEX and RFComm. which one is appropriate. and can you plz share a sample of code to show how to do it, it would be much appreciated.

Below is a sample code that i have found which uses OBEX to search for near by devices and its actually for image transferring. can you plz point out to me the part that are important and how to change this in order to send a stream of Data rather than picture... plz plz help

```
 public class BluetoothImageSender extends MIDlet implements CommandListener{

    public Display display;
    public Form discoveryForm;
    public Form readyToConnectForm;
    public Form dataViewForm;
    public ImageItem mainImageItem;
    public Image mainImage;
    public Image bt_logo;
    public TextField addressTextField;
    public TextField subjectTextField;
    public TextField messageTextField;
    public Command selectCommand;
    public Command exitCommand;
    public Command connectCommand;
    public List devicesList;
    public Thread btUtility;
    public String btConnectionURL;
    public boolean readData = false;
    public long startTime = 0;
    public long endTime = 0;

    public BluetoothImageSender() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            display = Display.getDisplay(this);
            discoveryForm = new Form("Image Sender");

            try{
                    mainImage = Image.createImage("/btlogo.png");
        bt_logo = Image.createImage("/btlogo.png");
            } catch (java.io.IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mainImageItem = new ImageItem("Bluetooth Image Sender", mainImage, Item.LAYOUT_CENTER, "");
            discoveryForm.append(mainImageItem);
            discoveryForm.append("\nThis application will scan the area for Bluetooth devices and determine if any are offering OBEX services.\n\n");

            /// discoveryForm initialization

            exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
            discoveryForm.addCommand(exitCommand);
            discoveryForm.setCommandListener(this);

            /// devicesList initialization

    devicesList = new List("Select a Bluetooth Device", Choice.IMPLICIT, new String[0], new Image[0]);
            selectCommand = new Command("Select", Command.ITEM, 1);
            devicesList.addCommand(selectCommand);
    devicesList.setCommandListener(this);
    devicesList.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[0]);

            /// readyToConnectForm initialization

            readyToConnectForm = new Form("Ready to Connect");
            readyToConnectForm.append("The selected Bluetooth device is currently offering a valid OPP service and is ready to connect. Please click on the 'Connect' button to connect and send the data.");
            connectCommand = new Command("Connect", Command.ITEM, 1);
            readyToConnectForm.addCommand(connectCommand);
            readyToConnectForm.setCommandListener(this);

            /// dataViewForm initialization

            dataViewForm = new Form("File Sending Progress");
            dataViewForm.append("Below is the status of the file sending process:\n\n");
            dataViewForm.addCommand(exitCommand);
            dataViewForm.setCommandListener(this);

}


    public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable d) {
            if(command == selectCommand) {
                    btUtility.start();
            }
            if(command == exitCommand ) {
                    readData = false;
                    destroyApp(true);
            }
            if(command == connectCommand ) {
                    Thread filePusherThread = new FilePusher();
                    filePusherThread.start();
                    display.setCurrent(dataViewForm);
            }
    }


    public void startApp() {
    display.setCurrent(discoveryForm);
    btUtility = new BTUtility();

    }


    public void pauseApp() {

    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean b) {
            notifyDestroyed();
    }
```

////////////////

```
/**
 * This is an inner class that is used for finding
 * Bluetooth devices in the vicinity.
 */
class BTUtility extends Thread implements DiscoveryListener {

    Vector remoteDevices = new Vector();
    Vector deviceNames = new Vector();

    DiscoveryAgent discoveryAgent;

    // obviously, 0x1105 is the UUID for
    // the Object Push Profile
    UUID[] uuidSet = {new UUID(0x1105) };

    // 0x0100 is the attribute for the service name element
    // in the service record
    int[] attrSet = {0x0100};


    public BTUtility() {
        try {
            LocalDevice localDevice = LocalDevice.getLocalDevice();
            discoveryAgent = localDevice.getDiscoveryAgent();
            discoveryForm.append(" Searching for Bluetooth devices in the vicinity...\n");
            discoveryAgent.startInquiry(DiscoveryAgent.GIAC, this);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void deviceDiscovered(RemoteDevice remoteDevice, DeviceClass cod) {
        try{
               discoveryForm.append("found: " + remoteDevice.getFriendlyName(true));
        } catch(Exception e){
           discoveryForm.append("found: " + remoteDevice.getBluetoothAddress());
        } finally{
               remoteDevices.addElement(remoteDevice);
            }
    }



    public void inquiryCompleted(int discType) {

        if (remoteDevices.size() > 0) {

            // the discovery process was a success
            // so out them in a List and display it to the user
            for (int i=0; i<remoteDevices.size(); i++){
                try{
                   devicesList.append(((RemoteDevice)remoteDevices.elementAt(i)).getFriendlyName(true), bt_logo);
                } catch (Exception e){
                   devicesList.append(((RemoteDevice)remoteDevices.elementAt(i)).getBluetoothAddress(), bt_logo);
                }
            }
            display.setCurrent(devicesList);
        } else {
                    // handle this
            }

    }


    public void run(){

        try {
            RemoteDevice remoteDevice = (RemoteDevice)remoteDevices.elementAt(devicesList.getSelectedIndex());
            discoveryAgent.searchServices(attrSet, uuidSet, remoteDevice , this);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void servicesDiscovered(int transID, ServiceRecord[] servRecord){

        for(int i = 0; i < servRecord.length; i++) {

            DataElement serviceNameElement = servRecord[i].getAttributeValue(0x0100);
            String _serviceName = (String)serviceNameElement.getValue();
            String serviceName = _serviceName.trim();
            btConnectionURL = servRecord[i].getConnectionURL(ServiceRecord.NOAUTHENTICATE_NOENCRYPT, false);
            System.out.println(btConnectionURL);
        }
        display.setCurrent(readyToConnectForm);
        readyToConnectForm.append("\n\nNote: the connection URL is: " + btConnectionURL);

    }

    public void serviceSearchCompleted(int transID, int respCode) {

        if (respCode == DiscoveryListener.SERVICE_SEARCH_COMPLETED) {
            // the service search process was successful

        } else {
            // the service search process has failed
        }

    }
```

}
////////////////

```
/**
 * FilePusher is an inner class that
 * now gets the byte[] named file
 * to read the bytes of the file, and
 * then opens a connection to a remote
 * Bluetooth device to send the file.
 */

class FilePusher extends Thread{

    FileConnection fileConn = null;
    String file_url = "/loginscreen.png";
    byte[] file = null;
    String file_name = "loginscreen.png";
    String mime_type = "image/png";

    // this is the connection object to be used for
    //  bluetooth i/o
    Connection connection = null;

    public FilePusher(){

    }



    public void run(){

        try{

            InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file_url);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // now read the file in into the byte[]
            int singleByte = 0;
            while(singleByte != -1){
                singleByte = is.read();
                os.write(singleByte);
            }

            System.out.println("file size: " + os.size());
            file = new byte[os.size()];
            file = os.toByteArray();

            dataViewForm.append("File name: " + file_url);
            dataViewForm.append("File size: " + file.length + " bytes");

            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error processing the file");
        }


        try{
            connection = Connector.open(btConnectionURL);
            // connection obtained

            // create a session and a headerset objects
            ClientSession cs = (ClientSession)connection;
            HeaderSet hs = cs.createHeaderSet();

            // establish the session
            cs.connect(hs);

            hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, file_name);
            hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, mime_type); // be sure to note that this should be configurable
            hs.setHeader(HeaderSet.LENGTH, new Long(file.length));

            Operation putOperation = cs.put(hs);

            OutputStream outputStream = putOperation.openOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(file);
            // file push complete

            outputStream.close();
            putOperation.close();

            cs.disconnect(null);

            connection.close();

            dataViewForm.append("Operation complete. File transferred");

            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = (endTime - startTime)/1000;
            System.out.println("Time to transfer file: " + diff);
            dataViewForm.append("Time to transfer file: " + diff);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error sending the file");
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

}